# Monodevelop: InvalidCastException when adding Web Reference using local WSDL

Tags: wcf, monodevelop

I am trying to add a Web Reference, using local WSDL/XSD files.

Unfortunately whenever I try, I get the exception below:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?
It works with online web services.

Here is the full exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaImporter.CollectAttributeUsesNonOverlap (System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaObjectCollection src, System.Xml.Serialization.ClassMap map) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaImporter.ImportAttributes (System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName typeQName, System.Xml.Serialization.ClassMap cmap, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaObjectCollection atts, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaAnyAttribute anyat, System.Xml.Serialization.CodeIdentifiers classIds) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaImporter.ImportMembersMappingComposite (System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaComplexType stype, System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName refer) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaImporter.ImportMembersMapping (System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporterInternal.ImportPartsBySchemaElement (System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName qname, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 parts, System.Web.Services.Description.Message msg, System.Web.Services.Description.MessagePart msgPart) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractImporterInternal.resolveMessage (System.Web.Services.Description.Message msg, System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageBodyDescription body, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 parts) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractImporterInternal.DoImportContract () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractImporterInternal.ImportContract (System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlImporter importer, System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlContractConversionContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter.System.ServiceModel.Description.IWsdlImportExtension.ImportContract (System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlImporter importer, System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlContractConversionContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlImporter.ImportContract (System.Web.Services.Description.PortType wsdlPortType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlImporter.ImportAllContracts () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.WebReferences.WCF.WebServiceDiscoveryResultWCF.CreateProxyFile (MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetProject dotNetProject, FilePath basePath, System.String proxyNamespace, System.String referenceName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.WebReferences.WebServiceDiscoveryResult.GenerateFiles (MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetProject project, System.String namspace, System.String referenceName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.WebReferences.Commands.WebReferenceCommandHandler.NewWebReference () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Same error with both `Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)` and `.NET 2.0 Web Services`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File a bug report at `bugzilla.xamarin.com` (use "Class Libraries" / "WCF") and include the WSDL that you're trying to import.

From looking at that stack trace, Mono's WSDL importer doesn't like your import for some reason.